# Studying power series of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to study where the following series is absolutely convergent:

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n + z^{-n}}{n^2}$

Well I know how to proceed because I already studied power series with real numbers. 
I first separated the series into a sum of series

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2} +  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{-n}}{n^2}$

Then well I calculated the radius of convergence by taking the limit of the absolute value of $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$
The radius is 1.

So he series might converge absolutely when $|z|<1 $ and $|\frac{1}{z}| < 1$. Well it diverges for all $\mathbb{C}$ except the condition we haven't studied yet: $|z| = 1$.
My question now is: how do I do this?
In real analysis it was easy, we just solved $|x| = 1$ and we got to $x=1$ and $x=-1$ and we just substitute in the series and studied it as a numerical series.

But now is different because $ |z| \neq z$

Can someone give a hint on how to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, one has to check all points on the circle $|z|=1$.

Comment: It diverges for $|z| = 1$ since $z^n+z^{-n}$ grows exponentially, and it converges for $|z|= 1$

Comment: @user1952009 What you just wrote is a contradiction...

Comment: @DonAntonio no, it is not a contradiction, but a typo

Comment: @user1952009 ...which forms a contradiction. Too late to change it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

$$|z|=1\implies z=e^{it}\implies z^n+z^{-n}=z^n+\overline {z^n}=2\text{Re}\,z^n=2\cos nt $$

So on the unit circle your series is just

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2\cos nt}{n^2}$$

which converges absolutely , for example because Weierstrass M-test:

$$\left|\frac{2\cos nt}{n^2}\right|\le\frac2{n^2}$$

Comment: we can also check if it is diferentiable

Comment: As the absolute convergence if for all $\;t\in\Bbb R\;$, it can be differentiated termwise everywhere.

Comment: It can be differentiated in $t$, but as a function in $z$ it is not even defined on an open set around any point, so it is not differentiable.

Comment: yes the termwise derivative $2\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{\sin(nt)}{n}$ converges by the Dirichlet test (the summation by parts) for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, so it is the derivative of the original series

Comment: Sry I meant $ = - 2\frac{t -\lfloor t/2\pi \rfloor-1/2}{\pi}$ and $2\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{\cos(nt)}{n^2} = 2\pi^2/6-\int_0^t  2\frac{x -\lfloor x/2\pi \rfloor-1/2}{\pi}dx$

Comment: @robjohn Very good point indeed.